# Best software product to simulate connectivity issues for mobile testing

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, ns2

I need a product to simulate network latency for testing mobile applications (in particular iphone and android).  I plan to set up a wifi router connected to a linux box, and write a number of scripts to approximate different types of connectivity issues.

So far, I've taken a cursory look at [Netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) and [ns-2](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/) ([or its offspring ns-3](http://www.nsnam.org/)).  Netem looks very easy to deploy and configure, but they both look like they'll require some in-depth investigation.

Does anyone have positive/negative experiences with either of those solutions that they could share?  Or maybe used a different solution for this problem?

Comment: I've heard of DeviceAnywhere but don't have firsthand experience.

Comment: I'm in the process of setting up an Ubuntu box with a network connection bridged through Netem to WIFI.  I'll update this question with my experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone comes here looking for tips, I've found a solution that seems to work well.

Ubuntu comes with [Netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) installed, so I went ahead and just made use of that.  Basically, I got a computer with two ethernet ports, forwarded one to the other and applied Netem latency settings to the connection.  Then I attached a wireless router to one, and LAN to the other.  Netem lets me play with all kinds of latency and packet loss settings.

Btw, I also tried to use a few different laptops and set the internal wireless card up as an ad-hoc wireless router.  I got it working for the most part, but finding a laptop with an internal wireless card that plays nice with ad-hoc in Linux is tricky at best... can't recommend it.

Comment: You can try installing a linux distribution such as Open-WRT on your Wireless Router and run Netem on it. I haven't tried it but heard that it works well

Comment: That's true, we could really cut the computer out altogether.  In my case, I preferred a full blown linux distro since there were other things I wanted to play around with, but yeah that's a good idea.